# Actionbar: inflate new menu resource

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` in my app with tabs. Each tab has its own `Fragment`.

In a `Fragment` class, `onCreateOptionsMenu` gets called, but just once.
Based on user input, I'd like to inflate a new menu resource, *after* the first time the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to dynamically change the ActionBar menu. Using if statements etc in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

When you need to re-run the logic call

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Which will recreate the menu items.